# Counting for every day individually

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I just created a table looking like this:

[image: Table]

I did this by putting the time-groups and the ChargingPoint-IDs (LPNumber) both as value into a table (the visualizations tool). As you can see I am counting the connections to a charging point (LPNumber) per time. Therefore I am spectating several days. So from 00:00 to 00:14 (grouped as 00:00 in row 1) there were a total of 36 connections made over a time period of 31 days.

My problem:

Only the starts of a connections are counted (obviously - I used ConnectionStart Time) but I want to count the connections which are active. So assuming that from the 36 connections which were made between 00:00 and 00:14, 10 connections are still active at 00:15, row 2 should be 10 + 25 = 35

As data I have the start-time and the end time of the connections and of course the LPNumber (the ID-number of the charging Point). I've got a lot more data but I think those 3 columns should be the only ones which are important.

[image: Data]

Do you have any idea how to realize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have data (`Table`) like this:

```
Start       End
00:00:00    00:14:00
00:10:00    00:20:00
00:20:00    00:30:00
00:22:00    00:40:00
00:31:00    00:50:00
00:00:00    01:00:00
```

And a timeslot (`Window`) table like this:

```
Start
00:00:00
00:15:00
```

You can add a calculated column to `Window` that counts the rows in `Table` which duration overlaps `Start + 14:59 min`

```
Col =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( 'Table' );
    FILTER (
        'Table';
        'Table'[Start]
            < ( Window[Start_Window] + TIME ( 0; 14; 59 ) )
            && 'Table'[End] > Window[Start_Window]
    )
)
```

If you need to generate the `Window` table you can use this formula:

```
Window = GENERATESERIES(TIME(0;0;0);TIME(23;59;00);TIME(0;15;0))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was Looking for! I use a time slicer which is referring to 'Table'[ConnectionStart'] but when I choose only one month the values in the calculated column include still the connections of all time. I tried including MIN('Table'[ConnectionStart]) and MAX('Table'[ConnectionStart]) in your FILTER() function but it didn't work.